# Git Clone Remote Self Hosted Repository

Tags: git, git-clone

Most solutions I found are about cloning from a GitHub or a Gitlab third-party host.  I would like to clone the repository from my server at home via SSH.  I kept on getting the error below.

Here are some contexts:

- I'm able to SSH and access those directories normally
- Git is initialized inside the test folder

**SSH Host Config**

```
Host my-server
  HostName my-server.domain.com
  Port 222
```

**Output**

```
$ git clone my-server:mnt/path/directory/test/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
username@my-server.domain.com's password: 

fatal: 'mnt/path/directory/test/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

$ git clone ssh://my-server:mnt/path/directory/test/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
username@my-server.domain.com's password:
fatal: 'mnt/path/directory/test/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

$ git clone ssh://my-server:222/mnt/path/directory/test/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
username@my-server.domain.com's 
fatal: 'mnt/path/directory/test/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


$ pwd
/mnt/path/directory/test

$ ls -lah                                   
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x. 3 username username 4.0K Feb 27 17:03 .
drwxr-xr-x. 7 username username 4.0K Feb 27 17:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 8 username username 4.0K Feb 27 18:32 .git
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username    0 Feb 27 17:03 test.txt
```

**Update #1**

The answer below is the solution but I had to use a different port number for the SSH session as mine is not set to the default port.

```
$ git clone ssh://username@my-server.domain.com:222:mnt/path/directory/test
Cloning into 'test'...
username@my-server.domain.com's password: 
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
```

I also included the username in the ~/.ssh/config and it worked as well.

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config

Host my-server
  HostName my-server.domain.com
  User username
  Port 222

$ git clone my-server:/mnt/path/directory/test
Cloning into 'test'...
username@my-server.domain.com's password: 
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
```

Comment: Try `git clone ssh://my-server:/mnt/path/directory/test/test.git`. Add the username if necessary, `git clone ssh://${username}@my-server:/mnt/path/directory/test/test.git`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things come to mind here:

1. As @ElpieKay mentioned in the comment, you need to specify a username, either in the clone command itself (`git clone username@my-server:/mnt/path/directory/test`) or in your `~/.ssh/config` (parameter in that file is `User username`; updated command would be `git clone my-server:/mnt/path/directory/test`).
2. Your `pwd` and `ls` output together suggest that you're using the wrong path in your clone command - `/mnt/path/directory/test/test.git` doesn't exist, but `/mnt/path/directory/test` does. Note that the absolute path is necessary if the repo isn't in `~username`, and that the colon doesn't separate hostname from path in the URL-style format (`git clone ssh://username@my-server/mnt/path/directory/test`).